# On what basis does VS Web Essentials 2013 v2 update/recompile LESS to CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, less

As a newbie to LESS I was expecting VS 2013 Web Essentials v2 to  help me learn by allowing me to focus on learning the syntax rather than the build tools. I've installed the latest version of Web Essentials and added it in Tools > Options > Extensions and Updates. I've download the latest version of Bootstrap source as well and extracted it to what I believe is a very simple directory structure:

- Root

  - Scripts (js files)
  - Bootstrap (less files)
  - Mine (less files) [ main.less, dependency.less ]
  - index.html

In main.less I have a single line: `@using 'dependency.less';` while in dependency.less I have a few valid less specifications.

Unfortunately, it has been tough for me to learn because when I refresh my page I can never be sure whether there has been no change because the file failed to compile, because the file hasn't compiled yet, or because I got the syntax wrong. For instance, toggling betewen `@using 'dependency.less'` and `@using './dependency.less'` usually forces an update, but simply saving my dependency file - even if I just made tons of changes - doesn't produce an update in the CSS.

So I am left wondering:

1. On what basis, if any, does Web Essentials decide to recompile the less files?
2. How can I force Web Essentials to recompile?

Comment: I have never used Web Essentials so I can't answer, but aren't there any pre-compilers for Windows out there, unrelated to Web Essentials? I use CodeKit on Mac which recompiles the LESS-files as soon as I save it. I imagine there must be something similar for Windows?..

Comment: I googled it. http://winless.org/

Comment: @PatrikAlienus yes there are, but isn't always nice to have one tool to get the job done?